# A question on graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Do there exist a family of graphs with the property:
$$\left|\alpha\left({G \boxtimes \bar{G}}\right) - \alpha\left({\overline{G \boxtimes \bar{G}}}\right)\right| = O(\log(N_{G}))$$
where $G$ is the graph, $\bar{G}$ is its complement, $\boxtimes$ denotes the strong product, $\alpha(G)$ denotes the independence number of $G$ and $N_{G}$ is the number of vertices of $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\alpha(\overline{K_n \boxtimes \overline{K_n}}) = n$$ and $$\alpha(K_n \boxtimes \overline{K_n}) = n$$ it follows that the family of complete graphs satisfies your assumptions.

To see the first equality observe that $K_n \boxtimes \overline{K_n}$ is the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $K_n.$ Hence in the complement every disjoint $K_n$ is an independent set any pair of vertices from disjoint copies of $K_n$ is adjacent.

Comment: New question posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468165/a-question-on-graphs

Comment: I've edited my answer so that you can see as to why the stated equality holds. Also, having $\alpha(H) =0 $ makes no sense.

Comment: I meant $=1$ (of course it does not make sense).

Comment: Is there such a $G$ that is self-complementary?

Comment: You mean a self complementary graph $G$ so that the above quantity is $0$?

Comment: no. the question is here: math.stackexchange.com/questions/468165/a-question-on-graphs